# I can't approve something I declined? - Flutter IOS activity access

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, permissions

During development, I permanently declined access to an activity on my phone, create functionality to allow it again, and did that manually from app settings, but not working, run flutter clean, remove and install the app again, from flutter SDK or/and from xCode directly but it not help.

```
Future<void> _requestPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.activityRecognition.request();
    setState(() {
      _status = status;
    });
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      ....
              onPressed: () {
                AppSettings.openAppSettings();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
      .....
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is "not working"?  Opening the app settings?  Granting the permission manually via app settings?

Comment: Yes, manually via app settings, and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you mean that you still have a "not granted" state for the permission?

Comment: Yea, exactly...